# delay advice - Huge resultset

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql multi select query that performs inner left joins. These queries UNION with two other tables. The resultset is huge (250k+ rows). My client wishes to expose this resultset to a webpage. The infinite scroll methodology used on the webpage calls the above query with an offset limit - 50 rows per call. The time taken to retrieve the above dataset is 7+secs.
Can anyone offer any advice as to how this delay could be reduced?

```
SELECT 'address_messages_unique' as db,`block_height`,`block_hash`, `block_timestamp`, `transaction_hash`, `data_hash`, `address_messages_unique`.`id`, `tags`, CONVERT(UNHEX(`address_messages_unique`.`data`) USING utf8mb4) as utf8_data, `mftm-Mess`.`MID`, `TTS`.`SSML`, `TTS`.`VoiceId`
FROM `messages_from_the_mines`.`address_messages_unique`
left join `mftm-Mess`
on `mftm-Mess`.`ID` = `address_messages_unique`.`id`
left join `TTS`
on `TTS`.`MID` = `mftm-Mess`.`MID`
UNION
SELECT 'coinbase_messages_unique' as db,`block_height`,`block_hash`, `block_timestamp`, `transaction_hash`, `data_hash`, `coinbase_messages_unique`.`id`, `tags`,CONVERT(UNHEX(`coinbase_messages_unique`.`data`) USING utf8mb4) as utf8_data, `mftm-Mess`.`MID`, `TTS`.`SSML`, `TTS`.`VoiceId`
FROM `messages_from_the_mines`.`coinbase_messages_unique`
left join `mftm-Mess`
on `mftm-Mess`.`ID` = `coinbase_messages_unique`.`id`
left join `TTS`
on `TTS`.`MID` = `mftm-Mess`.`MID`
UNION
SELECT 'op_return_address_messages_unique' as db, `block_height`, `block_hash`, `block_timestamp`, `transaction_hash`, `data_hash`, `op_return_address_messages_unique`.`id`, `tags`,CONVERT(UNHEX(`op_return_address_messages_unique`.`data`) USING utf8mb4) as utf8_data, `mftm-Mess`.`MID`, `TTS`.`SSML`, `TTS`.`VoiceId`
FROM `messages_from_the_mines`.`op_return_address_messages_unique`
left join `mftm-Mess`
on `mftm-Mess`.`ID` = `op_return_address_messages_unique`.`id`
left join `TTS`
on `TTS`.`MID` = `mftm-Mess`.`MID`
order by `block_height`
limit 0, 50;
```

The resultset (which essentailly is the output of the entire db needs to viewed page by page

Comment: Show the query, show `EXPLAIN {query}`. Show `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for each table in the query. What MySQL version? Also look at [pagination](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks  Akina - your message helped me get on the right track and sort this out:

> Copy this result to (temporary) table with additional autoincrement field (with the name `rownum`, for example, autoincrement field will (must) be PRIMARY KEY, so it will be filled with values automatically), then expose the data from this table and select first/next chunks by this field values (`WHERE rownum BETWEEN 50*@chunknum-49 AND 50*@chunknum`).

I ended up creating a new table using the previous resultset with the rownum autoincrement that you suggested